# using chkconfig to run multiple copies of a service

Tags: linux

im building a suse server.  i have multiple copies of postgres running on it.  i have the three instances running side by side just fine, the problem is when i try to get it to automatically start, i get this

```
 chkconfig -a postgresql5433
insserv: script postgresql5433: service postgresql already provided!
insserv: exiting now!
/sbin/insserv failed, exit code 1
postgresql5433            0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
```

so my first instance of postgres is running and auto starting on boot but the other two instances are not.

how do i fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the `INIT INFO` block used to order services with `chkconfig`:

For example:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: sshd
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $syslog
# Should-Start: $syslog
# Should-Stop: $network $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start up the OpenSSH server daemon
# Description:       SSH is a protocol for secure remote shell access.
#                    This service starts up the OpenSSH server daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

You'll likely have to change the `Provides:` line to a new unique value.